# dcommit only a certain local (i.e. git) branch with git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-branch

I am developing using `git` but I have to publish via `svn`.
That's why I've set up `git-svn` (by `git svn clone`).

My usual workflow is like this:

```sh
git svn rebase  # get local git repository up-to-date
git add file    # add some code
git commit      # commit code to local git repository
git svn dcommit # push changes from local git repository to public svn repository
```

So far this works fine.

However, I would like to create a branch (say `secret`) in my local `git` repository that is completely ignored by `git-svn`.

I guess I have to do something like this:

```sh
git svn rebase      # get local git repository up-to-date
git branch secret   # create secret branch in local git repository
git checkout secret # switch to secret branch in local git repository
git add secret.file # add some secret code
git commit          # commit secret code to secret branch of local git repository
git checkout master # switch back to public branch in local git repository
git svn rebase      # get public branch of local git repository up-to-date
git add public.file # add some public code
git commit          # commit public code to public branch of local git repository
git svn dcommit     # push public changes from local git repository to public svn repository
```

Would this workflow keep `secret.file` completely hidden from `svn`?
If so, I guess I could just `git merge` it into `master` and `git svn dcommit` it to the `svn` it once it gets *'un-classified'*. Is that correct?

Also, would it be possible to rename `master` to `public` for clarity?
If so, how? Note that there is already a history for that branch in both repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your secret changes will stay in your local git until you do `git checkout secret && git svn dcommit` or merge your changes to other branch (`master`/`public`) and dcommit from there.

Instead of renaming master to public, you could simply start public: 

`git checkout master
git checkout -b public
git commit, etc...
git svn dcommit`

Branches will "remember" svn branch they were started from, you may always check this with `git svn info`. You could optionally drop master after switching to public: `git branch -D master`